# How can I make a site viewable in multiple languages?

Tags: multi-language, accessibility

I am aware of the question [What are options are there to implement a multi language site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-are-options-are-there-to-implement-a-multi-language-site), but the answers there are focused on multi-language support on the backend as well as the frontend.

I am only concerned with offering multi-language viewing of a site's content, not multi-language content creation.

Could it be as simple as putting the [Google Translate Tools](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) code on my site? I see that there are at least [a](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-ajax-translation/) [couple](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/global-translator/) of plugins that offer this functionality - anyone have experience with those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your just looking for a way for your site to be viewed in other languages I would defiantly recommend using Google Translate Tools.  I just add it to the theme:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"><span id="trans">Translate: </span></div>
```

You can hide the Google Logo and funky colors in your css:

```
.goog-logo-link{display:none;}
```

Instead of calling the Google Translate js I just copy the return script and add it to my main js file.

**Edit**

Google provides [embed code](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) to use on your website:

```
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

The first line: `<div id="google_translate_element"></div>` can be placed where you want the translate drop down box to be shown:

[image]

The section between the first set of `<script>` tags are the language and layout options.  The last set of `<script>` tags call more javascript which Google inserts inline in your html while the dom is loading.  To speed up this process and avoid the extra http request and inline script I remove the last call and add the code returned by Google into a "master" js file I use that contains all my custom javascript combined into one file.  The code that Google returns is:

```
(function(){var d=window,e=document;function f(b){var a=e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];a||(a=e.body.parentNode.appendChild(e.createElement("head")));a.appendChild(b)}function _loadJs(b){var a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.charset="UTF-8";a.src=b;f(a)}function _loadCss(b){var a=e.createElement("link");a.type="text/css";a.rel="stylesheet";a.charset="UTF-8";a.href=b;f(a)}function _isNS(b){b=b.split(".");for(var a=d,c=0;c<b.length;++c)if(!(a=a[b[c]]))return false;return true}
function _setupNS(b){b=b.split(".");for(var a=d,c=0;c<b.length;++c)a=a[b[c]]||(a[b[c]]={});return a}d.addEventListener&&typeof e.readyState=="undefined"&&d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){e.readyState="complete"},false);
if (_isNS('google.translate.Element')){return}var c=_setupNS('google.translate._const');c._cl='en';c._cuc='googleTranslateElementInit';c._cac='';c._cam='';var h='translate.googleapis.com';var b=(window.location.protocol=='https:'?'https://':'http://')+h;c._pah=h;c._pbi=b+'/translate_static/img/te_banner_bk.gif';c._pci=b+'/translate_static/img/te_ctrl.gif';c._phf=h+'/translate_static/js/element/hrs.swf';c._pli=b+'/translate_static/img/loading.gif';c._plla=h+'/translate_a/l';c._pmi=b+'/translate_static/img/mini_google.png';c._ps=b+'/translate_static/css/translateelement.css';c._puh='translate.google.com';_loadCss(c._ps);_loadJs(b+'/translate_static/js/element/main.js');})();
```

This is mainly for performance reasons to avoid the extra request and avoids the website having to communicate with Google unless a language is chosen from the drop down box.

The drop down box can be customized using css.  For example here is how I display the box on the site I used it on.

[image]

Comment: Chris_O, can you add a little detail regarding the javascript part of your answer? I'm not very familiar wwith JS, so I'm not sure what you mean by "copy the return script".

Comment: @tnorthcutt see edits above.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the additions! Very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

please see this question [Best practices for localizing WordPress content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content/1589#1589) maybe you find an solution from this ideas

Answer (score 0):

I'm using qTranslate plugin for a project that i'm developing and i'm really happy with the results..

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/

Cheers