# Fancy-box Esay wordpress plugin fails to work on Multilingual site

Tags: theme-development, jquery

I have a multi lingual site.
On the site I want to display youtube movies using fancybox (or any other equivalent solution)

The plugin is installed and set.
When checked on the He version - all works well.
On En on the other side, it redirects to youtube.

EN: http://www.mtbsuisse.com/en/category/videos/
HE:  http://www.mtbsuisse.com/category/videos/

Any idea why this happens ?

I am using qtranslate for the multilingual support

*Changed site default to HE for now

Comment: I do not see any difference between your links. You should probably share your needs with the author of the plugin to find a solution. That's to tell the author of the fancybox plugin that you would love to see it work with qtranslate.

Comment: Even after you last change: Both sites work the same for me. I click on the video picture which are linked to the youtube page. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a different solution.
Just replaced [wp-fancybox-easy](http://www.wordpress-plugin.org/plugin/easy-fancybox-plugin/) with [wp-lightpop](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-lightpop/).
Wp-lightpop works wonderfully out of the box.
2 changed I needed to do were:
1. go to the setting page and change the links to be displayed as popup (otherwise it's open the language navigation links as overlay)
2. change box style (look&feel)

Problem solved :-)

Comment: Great to read that you solved your question. Using an alternative plugin can actually help as well. So true :).

Answer (score 2):

You are most certainly experience a "incompatibility" between the add-on that you use for multiple languages and the [Easy Fancy-box (wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/).

As Wordpress does not support multiple languages natively, most of the plugins available do not support it either. For more information about multiple languages, please see [What are options are there to implement a multi language site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-are-options-are-there-to-implement-a-multi-language-site).

To find a solution for your issue, you need to find out how a plugin can support your multi-languages feature. You have not written how you added multiple languages to your blog, so this can not be answered with your question. If done by a plugin you normally find the information for that on the plugins homepage or forum or in the [wordpress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) provided by other users.

### Update:

Now that you added that you're using the [qtranslate (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/), you can do the following: Ensure that this is not a configuration issue on your side. If not, get in contact with the author of the fancybox plugin and tell that you would love to see it offering compability with a multi-lingual site with qtranslate. qtranslate is quite popular so some plugin authors are willing to add support for it.