# Suggestions for i18n plugin

Tags: plugins, translation

Could you please suggest me good plugins (that you have used) for translating a WordPress website? It should be wonderful if you can add as well a pros and cons list with your suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hat tip to you for making me learn what "i18n" means (it's a numeronym for internationalization). https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Numeronym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll speak for qTranslate, I've used it a few times and been pretty happy with it. What it sets out to do - letting you offer translations of post content in multiple languages and switch between them - it does pretty well.

It gets a bit dicey when you try to extend it beyond alternate language versions of posts, though. I had to hack a lot to use the language filters on category titles and descriptions, for instance, or products with different currencies, etc.

For the most part, qtranslate's approach is pretty straightforward: you put the various languages within shortcodes so the title "My Title" would be entered like this:

`[lang_en]My Title[/lang_en][lang_es]Mi Titulo[/lang_es] ...`

The plugin hacks up the default post editor nicely to handle that bit transparently to you. But if you want to translate other parts of the site - widget content, etc. - you have to enter that markup yourself. Works well for basic blogs, but if you're trying to do more with internationalization, you might want to look at some of the other discussions that have happened about offering multi-lingual content. Here's a few:

- [What are options are there to implement a multi language site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-are-options-are-there-to-implement-a-multi-language-site)
- [Best practices for localizing WordPress content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content/)

Answer (score 2):

While the latest version is not free, [WPML](http://wpml.org/) seems to be the most complete and best supported plugin for multilingual sites.

Comment: Awww when did they start charging for this? I was planning on using this in the future. Shame its now a pay for plugin.

Comment: One friend suggested me qTranslate as well. Let's see if anyone will recommend it.

Comment: @Brady Some time after 2011-04-27, as that's the date of the last update they released via the WordPress plugin repo. That being said, the 2.0.4.1 release is still in the repo under http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/

Answer (score 0):

great post. Our company has developed a WordPress plugin for translation of websites. It povides high quality translation by allowing post-editing of machine translated content using a translation community. And it is free. More information on http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gts-translation/