# Best Wordpress Multi-language Plugin?

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml, plugin-qtranslate

What is the best multi-language plugin for WordPress?

WordPress does not have multi-language support itself, so you need to use a plugin to obtain multi-language functionality. Do not suggest the usage of different WordPress sites for obtaining the multi-language functionality because this would create more problems that solving.

Please answer only if you successfully implemented such solution and explain what current limitation it has. Also it would be a good idea to specify what other solutions you tested before choosing this one.

Things to consider:

- language URLs, like /en/... /fr/..
- being able to fallback to default language for untranslated pages
- browser language detection

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [725](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-are-options-are-there-to-implement-a-multi-language-site)

Comment: This is not an duplicate of 725, this one asks for one recommandation, not many.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to recommend [WPML](http://wpml.org), I use it on all of my bi/multi-lingual projects. It has great support and it makes WordPress truly multilingual, instead of only your content.

The latest addition is the media module, which takes care of the images you upload to Posts and Pages. No need anymore to upload them for each language separately, the plugin now recognises that there is an image attached to one language and will ask you to use that image too or not.

Any questions you have about it, you can let me know.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that WPML is a commercial plugin, but in my opinion it definetly is the most advanced solution for implementing multilingual on your website. I like it also because it has plugins, which let you activate only the functionalities you really need. The interfacing with [iCanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/) is also quite unique.

Comment: I do agree with WPML as the best solution however it's quite complicated to use for customers not used to Wordpress administration.

Comment: -1 for WPML backstabbing me and becoming paid software. I was forced to buy the upgrade for a customer that had an old version that wasn't working anymore since WP3+.

Answer (score 4):

My vote for [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) it supports a lot of languages and is very configurable :)

Comment: A new version of qTranslate is available - mqTranslate. I've used it for one of my projects and recommend it. https://wordpress.org/plugins/mqtranslate/installation/

Comment: Also: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated Translate from 1.2 to 1.3. Very simple plug-in, meaning easy to customize. Main advantage is that everything in on one post or page.

Answer (score 0):

[GTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gtranslate/)  Am Using This one.Get translations with a single click between 58 languages (more than 98% of internet users) on your website!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Best WordPress Multilanguage Plugins](http://www.wpmayor.com/plugin-reviews/best-wordpress-multilanguage-plugins/) for a discussion about this. I believe WPML is leading now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few  but I found mLanguage to be the easiest to impliment.

It does not translate - its not clear in your post if you want multi language, or a translator.  They are obviously very different

put in [en] what you want in english[/en][fr]french[/fr] and the text comes up only in the language selected. outside the [] will be on every language.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Rosetta plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rosetta-free/) it comes as a free version and a paid one.

> Rosetta plugin for WordPress is designed to give the user a simple and
>   effective way to build a multi-language website. It makes it possible
>   to easily produce and manage multilingual content.

This free version of Rosetta plugin has some limitations.

**Here is a quick overview of free version features:**

- Multi-language from the box - everything required already included
- Quick and simple configuration. Host versatility - use pre-configured
- host names or form automatic URLs. Multilingual post content editing
- via tabs in post edit WordPress section Website title, description
- and menu localization Language switching widget Plugin localization
  support

Read more about it here: http://store.theme.fm/plugins/stella/
And here is the plugin documention: http://store.theme.fm/files/2012/06/Stella-Documentation.pdf